# rgbdslam: No definition of [octomap] for OS version [raring]

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, rosdep, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm new to ROS; I'm trying to install RGBD-Slam Package, when I entered "rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg" in terminal, this error: " rgbdslam: No definition of [octomap] for OS version [raring] " apeared, I don't know what should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65894/rgbdslam:-no-definition-of-%5Boctomap%5D-for-os-version-%5Braring%5D/) by [Mohsen.X55](https://answers.ros.org/users/5231/mohsen.x55/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#groovy-galapagos-oct-2012) the supported target platforms for Groovy do not include Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring). Have you installed all the core ROS packages yourself from source? Then this might work if you install & compile octomap yourself, and all other dependencies of RGBD-Slam.

Otherwise you will have to try out ROS hydro (alpha version), or use an older version of Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen.X55](https://answers.ros.org/users/5231/mohsen.x55/) on 2013-06-25**:
No I didn't install all the Core ROS packages from source